# The latest kernel update got corrupted during install, I booted into the previous version. How do I clean out and reinstall the new kernel?

Tags: kernel

I think the new kernel version - 6.20 - encountered a problem during installation and was only partially installed, or something. When I booted into it, my keyboard wasn't recognized (even though it worked in GRUB), my wi-fi was dead, and other issues. I booted up again and selected the previous kernel version in GRUB.

How can I remove any traces of the possibly botched 6.2 install and re-do it cleanly? the software updater program gives me this:

[image]

Ubuntu 22

Comment: Use the command line. Run `sudo apt update`, followed by `apt full-upgrade --dry-run` to simulate the upgrade. If it works well (do check the error messages (if any) and removed packages in the output), upgrade with `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: The extra caution of `--dry-run` might be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the initrd didn't build successfully and drivers were missing when you tried to boot.  A common cause of this is lack of sufficient disk space to complete the update, but examining the logs would tell for sure.

Make sure you have sufficient disk space in /tmp and /boot and then retry the update from the command line:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

If this fails, it may have additional instructions you should follow, like running `dpkg -configure -a` which may complete an aborted previous package install.

If this all works, you may want to run `apt full-upgrade` to install additional updates.

If you get additional errors that you are unable to resolve, you should add them to the question or ask a new question.

Likely the update is not corrupt, just not complete.
If it is actually corrupt and you can identify which package is corrupt, you could reinstall it with `apt install --reinstall package...`